# Is it okay to duplicate an answer after the existing one was accepted over 2 years ago?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/72475/10132) was submitted about 2 months ago, but appears to be a duplicate of the answer that was posted over two and a half years earlier, which was already marked as the accepted answer. Is this allowed?

I flagged it to the mods just over a day ago but the flag still says pending, so I wasn't sure if maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Funny you should post this as it seems to be a duplicate of other questions here on meta. Previously general consensus was to simply downvote and the answer and perhaps leave a comment if one hasn't been left yet so they learn not to do it and other people see that it isn't accepted here. As far as I know it shouldn't be a problem that you flagged it though, and the time its taken to be addressed is likely just due to moderators being busy or not checking right now.